# Hi i have a blocking error in vb 2008.In my project i used excel 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a blocking error in vb 2008( windows forms application ).

In my project I used excel 2010. I have added the statement `'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'` in my program.  I got a error that it is not a namespace member.

I learned that I need go add reference of a library component and so I downloaded and installed primary interop assembly service for excel 2010. Even now if I add my reference I get no change in components.

Still the same error.

help please.its urgent

Answer (score 1):

Have you Office installed?
If not, you cannot use Interop.

If you have installed Office you should add a reference:
Go to my project -> references -> add -> com -> microsoft.excel.12(14).library. Then it should work. The 14 denotes that, depending on your version, the exact number will vary.

If you have no excel installed, you could try EPPLUS: http://epplus.codeplex.com/
It is a great library to read / write xlsx files, much more quickly and more comprehensible than interop.